# A field already has access to the other foreign key in a table

Tags: django, django-models

```
class User(models.Model):
     ...


class Phone(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone = models.TextField()

class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_phone = models.OneToOneField(Phone)
```

Already user field in profile has access to phone, So is this design ok or bad based on a normalization view?

Comment: Do you really need the whole model for a phone?

Comment: Don't need it actually , but that makes a schema change. So I was just wondering if it breaks any Normalization principle.

Comment: I find it odd that the `Phone` has a `user`. Basically your `Profile` acts as a junction-table between `User` and `Phone`.

Comment: Furthermore it is a bit "odd" that a `Phone` number links to the `User`. Why not make use of the `Profile` to link these two.

Comment: Your modeling is definitely bad in some manner. If a user may have multiple phones then I would modify your models as such: Remove `user_phone` from `profile` and in `Phone` change the foreign key to point to `profile` instead of `User`. Also rename `profile` to `Profile` for following better conventions. Plus a user should have only one profile yes? Use a one to one field instead of a foreign key for that relation.

Comment: I understand that the modeling is bad. `Phone` model takes care of login and has lot of data.  `Profile` was  a later addition. So I need to maintain the `Phone` model. So I was wondering if its beneficial to make a field `user_phone` or just use `user` to access the `phone`

Comment: @JissRaphel: but it looks like you made a *custom* user model, in that case you can simply store data in your custom user model, and thus there is no need for a `Profile` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modeling is quite *strange*. Your `Phone` model has a `ForeignKey` to the `User` model. Furthermore your `Profile` seems to act as a junction-table between `User` and `Phone`.

Since you made a custom user model, there is no need for a `Profile` model, and definitely not one with a relation to the `Phone` model.

You can simply extend your `User` model with extra fields that you want to store (that are now in the `Profile` model), and then make use of a `ForeignKey` from `Phone` to user to specify that that phone (there can be zero, one or multiple) belongs to that user, so something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    # …
    # fields for the user and 
    # extra data that was stored in
    # the Profile model


class Phone(models.Model):
    phone = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='phones'
    )
```